# add instance method using open class to Object class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, block

I have a class `Operator` that executes a block of code of some instances of other objects:

```
class Operator

    def operation(&block)
        #execution of a block in some object
    end
end
```

In the other hand, I have the class Criature

```
class Criature

    operational

    def level_up
        @level+=1
    end

end
```

And I need to monkeypatch the class `Object` with open class.

So, I need to define the method `operational` in `Object` , because, every time that an instance of `Operator` executes `operation`, with (for example) the block: `{ c.level_up() }` will be executed for every instance with `operational` in it's class body.

How can I do to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with having a `module` and then `include Operator`?

Comment: the execution has to be in Operator, the criatures are not he ones that fire the execution, so i can't pass the instance as parameter neither.

Comment: What I'm talking about is the traditional Ruby mixin strategy. When you `include` some code, the execution context is the instance into which it's included. It becomes a part of that class, an instance method like any other.

Comment: yes i know, but, with that way, how can I do to everytime that I execute the ´operation´ method (with only a block as a parameter, and  no copy of the instances) to execute the block on every instance that includes the mixin?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the `operation` method is. Based on your description it sounds like you want to include some kind of stub in your code where you'd iterate over all instances of a given class and execute some kind of block? That's an extremely unusual way of implementing something, and it's bound to have problems. It's much better to aggregate the instances in a set, array, or container of some sort so the iteration is explicit and clear, not magical and mysterious.

Comment: You could do this in `initialize` by calling `Operator.register(self)` or something like that to make it clear you're allowing it to take charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> executes a block of code of some instances of some objects:

If I well understand, with the method

```
    operational
```

that you want to execute in the body of some classes like `Criature`, you want to flag their instances, saying "Hey, give me a call when `operation` is performed."

From [The Pickaxe](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) :

> **ObjectSpace.each_object( ‹ class_or_mod› )**
>
> Calls the block once for each living, nonimmediate object in this Ruby process. If class_or_mod is specified, calls the block for only those classes or modules that match (or are a subclass of) class_or_mod.

With `ObjectSpace` it's possible to iterate over the objects of a certain class. This gives me the idea that the signature, this flag that you want to give to certain instances, can be accomplished with a superclass.

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Operational)
```

will collect all instances of classes having this "signature".

File `tc.rb` :

```
class Operational
    
end

class Criature < Operational
    def initialize(p_name)
        @name  = p_name
        @level = 0
    end
        
    def level_up
        @level+=1
        puts "level is now #{@level}"
    end
end

class XYZ < Operational
    def initialize(p_name)
        @name = p_name
    end
    
end
```

File `to.rb` :

```
require_relative 'tc'

class Operator

    def operation(&block)
        #execution of a block in some object
        Special.currently_operational.each do | obj |
            puts "operation on #{obj.inspect}"
            block.call(obj) if obj.respond_to? 'level_up'
        end
    end
end

class Special
    def self.currently_operational
        operationals = []

        ObjectSpace.each_object(Operational) do | object |
            operationals << object
        end

        puts "#{operationals.size} objects are flagged as operational"
        operationals
    end
end

Criature.new('c1')
Criature.new('c2')
Criature.new('c3')

block = Proc.new{ | x | x.level_up }
puts 'first round'
Operator.new.operation(&block)

# later ...
XYZ.new('x1')
XYZ.new('x2')

puts 'second round'
Operator.new.operation(&block)
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w to.rb 
first round
3 objects are flagged as operational
operation on #<Criature:0x007fc45683d2f0 @name="c3", @level=0>
level is now 1
operation on #<Criature:0x007fc45683d368 @name="c2", @level=0>
level is now 1
operation on #<Criature:0x007fc45683d3b8 @name="c1", @level=0>
level is now 1
second round
5 objects are flagged as operational
operation on #<XYZ:0x007fc45683cad0 @name="x2">
operation on #<XYZ:0x007fc45683cb48 @name="x1">
operation on #<Criature:0x007fc45683d2f0 @name="c3", @level=1>
level is now 2
operation on #<Criature:0x007fc45683d368 @name="c2", @level=1>
level is now 2
operation on #<Criature:0x007fc45683d3b8 @name="c1", @level=1>
level is now 2
```

Comment: Edited with your block call.